# Transport failed: Could not transport tcm_0-666089-66560.Content.zip using HTTPS.Cause:Execution Timeout

Tags: publishing, 2013, deployer

I see few components of large size are not getting published to specific publication targets.
i verified the package size in the cd_deployer_conf.xml file and found the value set to maximum.
When i observerd the cd_core logs i found the below error.

> 2014-06-03 12:27:05,439 ERROR ParallelDestinationWorker - Timeout of 60000 ms exceeded for transaction tcm:0-666089-66560
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
>       at com.tridion.transport.workers.ParallelDestinationWorker.blockAndGetResult(ParallelDestinationWorker.java:111) ~[cd_transport.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.transport.workers.ParallelTransportWorker.doWork(ParallelTransportWorker.java:49) [cd_transport.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.StepTransport.execute(StepTransport.java:55) [cd_transport.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.StepPrepare$1.run(StepPrepare.java:59) [cd_transport.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
>   2014-06-03 12:27:05,442 ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - Unable to execute HTTP POST
>   java.io.InterruptedIOException: Connection has been shut down
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:543) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
>       at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.HTTPSTransportConnector.send(HTTPSTransportConnector.java:384) ~[cd_transport.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.TransportPoolConnector.send(TransportPoolConnector.java:92) [cd_transport.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.transport.workers.TransportSender.call(TransportSender.java:78) [cd_transport.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.transport.workers.TransportSender.call(TransportSender.java:27) [cd_transport.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
>   Caused by: org.apache.http.impl.conn.ConnectionShutdownException: null
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.assertValid(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:86) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:120) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:636) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
>       ... 11 common frames omitted

Based on the error about execution timeout, i modified the session execution timeout value present in TridionContentManager.config from 60 to 3600 and restarted the COM+.
But i see the same error after publishing it again.
Please let me know if i need to modify at some other location.

Comment: Did you restart the Tridion Content Deployer windows service or your Deployer website if using HTTP Deployer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try increasing the SendTimeout on the Senders element in cd_transport_conf.xml.  The default is 60s.

e.g. to increase it to 90s:

```
<Senders SendTimeout="90000">
```

Documented [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-9F5A4E2A-DFFC-4D36-9556-216E78604377) (login required).

Comment: Thankyou so much.This configuration helped.

Answer (score 0):

can you try playing with values in following in httpupload web.config?

```
  <system.web>
    <!-- 50MB in kilobytes, default is 4096 or 4MB-->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" />   </system.web>   <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- 50MB in bytes, default is 30000000 or approx. 28.6102 Mb-->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" /> 
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>   </system.webServer>
```